# Why won't div's height expand to its child elements?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm still in the process of mastering css.

So I've made my portfolio website from scratch. as you scroll you'll see the main content is made up of a two column layout. My columns are fixed, wrapped in a relative div that takes up 100% width. the two fixed divs inside take up 50% width. Then I put content inside of the fixed divs -- like my portfolio.
But sometimes the fixed divs height don't expand to the height of the content within it. Especially when you resize. Why?

Here's a link to my website so you can see what I mean. 
http://parkhargravedesigns.com/

```js
if ($(window).width() > 768) {

  $('.f, .fixedContainer').css('height', $('.text').height());
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('.f, .fixedContainer').css('height', $('.text').height());
  });

  $('.f2,.fixedContainer2').css('height', $('.text2').height());
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('.f2,.fixedContainer2').css('height', $('.text2').height());
  });


  $('.f3, .fixedContainer3').css('height', $('.text3').height());
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('.f3, .fixedContainer3').css('height', $('.text3').height());
  });

}
```

```css
.fixedContainer,
.fixedContainer2,
.fixedContainer3 {
  position: relative!important;
  width: 100%!important;
}

.headerEle2 {
  display: block!important;
}

.f,
.f2,
.f3 {
  background-color: #293553;
  background-size: cover!important;
  width: 50%!important;
  position: absolute!important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.f2 {
  background-color: #e7384c!important;
}

.text,
.text2,
.text3 {
  background-color: white!important;
  background-size: cover!important;
  color: black;
  position: absolute!important;
  right: 0!important;
  top: 0!important;
  width: 50%!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixedContainer">
  <div class="f">
    <div id="aboutStuff">
      <p class="fTitle">
        About
      </p>
      <div class="headerEle2 NavDiv"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="profilePic">
    <img src="album/profilePic2.png" alt="oops">
  </div>
  <div class="text">

    <h1>I'M A WEB &amp; GRAPHIC DESIGNER FROM B.C, CANADA.</h1>
    <p>
      A strong interest in art and design was my gateway to the creative industry, which led to taking my first steps in the digital world. During my time at North Island College I fell inlove with web design because it allowed me to express my creativity while
      developing the skills necessary to create functionable websites.

    </p>

    <h1>SERVICES:</h1>

    <p>

      <b>Website Design and Development Logo Design</b>
    </p>


    <h1>QUALIFICATIONS:</h1>
    <p>

      <b>HTML
        CSS
        JavaScript
        JQuery
        Illustrator
        Photoshop
      </b>
    </p>

    <h1>EDUCATION:</h1>
    <p>
      <b>Program:</b> Web Design &amp; Interactive Media Certificate
      <b>Where:</b> North Island College, Comox Valley, BC In this program I gained skills in HTML,<br> CSS, Javascript, PHP and Adobe CC.

    </p>
    <h1>DESIGN PROCESS</h1>
    <p>
      A user-centered mindset and sensitivity for design are <br> key concepts I carry throughout the design process.<br><br> This rough framework outlines my process of<br> developing digital experiences: 1. RESEARCH and gather the present state 2. STRUCTURE
      setup and content of the project 3. CONCEPT AND STRATEGY <br> 4. CREATE, evaluate and iterate deliverables like &nbsp;-Site maps &nbsp;-User flow &nbsp;-Sketches and Infographics &nbsp;-Wireframes
    </p>

    <!--
   <img src = "album/homeFixed.png" alt = "oops" id = "text1Logo">
    -->

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: because you have positioned the children absolutely - absolute positioning removes the element from the natural flow of the page so it won't take up any space.  I would use a different approach to your layout - absolute positioning should mainly be reserved for moving elements, drop downs, modals and other such elements that need to appear on top of other elements

Comment: Also try not to use `!important` so much (as you will get into a situation where everything is important just to overwrite the last important) - it should only be used as a last resort to overwrite inline css that you cannot get access to - I always feel as though I have failed if I ever need to use it, and now only limit it's usage to overwriting 3rd party plugin js inline styles

Comment: yes but can't I put other elements inside an absolute div? how could I get around this while keeping the same format?

Comment: I would go and learn flex or grid css (grid is meant to be the future but is not widely supported at the moment).  With flex it is really easy to do a column layout without the need for absolute positioning and you get the added bonus of having equal height columns if you want

Comment: CSS Grid seems pretty well supported to me: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid; though I admit that IE11 support could be better. Plus any browser that supports `display: grid` also supports the `@supports( display: grid )` to implement a non-grid implementation on older browsers, and a grid implementation in supporting browsers.

Comment: @Pete Every current browser supports flex except IE (of course but poorly) and every current browser supports grid except IE (of course but poorly).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my container div not expanding to show the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677773/why-is-my-container-div-not-expanding-to-show-the-content)

Comment: @Rob I count flex as full support as the only bugs I see with IE11 (not bothered about earlier as not supported by microsoft) is that the default values are not the same as the other browsers, most of the other bugs have work arounds and as always I say punish dumb ie users, if they don't know better than to upgrade their browser then they don't deserve the full richness the web offers

Comment: @ParkHargrave Just a comment: *Very heavy image http://parkhargravedesigns.com/album/gig.png `25.8 MB`. Crushes my browser. I'd recommend to reduce the images weights.*